# How to make async http request in rails

Tags: ruby, http, ruby-on-rails-4, asynchronous

In my rails app, I need to make a http request to 3rd party service, since http request is synchronous, sometimes it takes more than 20 seconds to get response back from them.

I just push some data to that service, I don't care about what the response will be, so I want to make the request asynchronous, so my code will continue execution and not been blocked.

*How could I do it in ruby?*

Comment: you should check out [ActiveJobs](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html) and [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq)

Comment: I don't want a queue solution, because I reckon it is overkilling for a simple http request. Would EventMachine defer be a good solution?

Answer (score 6):

> I need to make a http request...so my code will continue execution and not been blocked.

```
def some_action
  Thread.new do
    uri = URI('http://localhost:4567/do_stuff')
    Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, 'x' => '1', 'y' => '2')
  end

  puts "****Execution continues here--before the response is received."
end
```

Here's a sinatra app you can use to test it:

1) `$ gem install sinatra`

2)

```
#my_sinatra_app.rb

require 'sinatra'

post '/do_stuff' do
  puts "received: #{params}" #Check the sinatra server window for the output.
  sleep 20  #Do some time consuming task.

  puts "Sending response..."
  "The result was: 30"   #The response(which the rails app ignores).
end
```

**output**:

```
$ ruby my_sinatra_app.rb
== Sinatra (v1.4.6) has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from Thin
Thin web server (v1.6.4 codename Gob Bluth)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on localhost:4567, CTRL+C to stop

received: {"x"=>"1", "y"=>"2"}
<20 second delay>
Sending response...

127.0.0.1 - - [11/Nov/2015:12:54:53 -0400] "POST /do_stuff HTTP/1.1" 200 18 20.0032
```

When you navigate to `some_action()` in your rails app, the rails server window will immediately output `****Execution continues here--before the response is received.`, and the sinatra server window will immediately output the `params` hash, which contains the data sent in the post request.   Then after a 20 second delay the sinatra server window will output `Sending response...`.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but seems like there is a problem, since the  http request is executed in a new thread, and the client terminated immediately, the sinatra app never receive the request. If I add a line at the end of the client code `sleep 10` , then it works, any idea how to remedy this?

Comment: @xiaopang, If you write `t = Thread.new...`, and then at the end of the client you add `t.join` then the client won't exit until after the Thread finishes executing.  You can add a timeout in seconds: `t.join(500)`.

Comment: Yep, it works this way, but it missed the whole point of none blocking, right? : )

Comment: @xiaopang, I changed my comment.  *it missed the whole point of none blocking, right?* Yeah...any code before the `t.join` will execute before the response is received, but if there's no other code in your action, the view isn't going to render until after the response is received. :(

Comment: @xiaopang, *the client terminated immediately*--Can you explain how you are doing that?  What is your client?  As far as I can tell, the client of the Sinatra app is your Rails app.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use Event Machine and Fibers in ruby.

[Github: em-http-request](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-http-request/)

Comment: Hi @harshit, can you elaborate a bit ? I tried Event Machine, but according to [this doc](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine#server-example-echo-server), the code execution is still blocking